# how to set the fieldname using a template in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to have some interaction of the label for a field with the field validation properties.
I created a plunker of a working example.

http://plnkr.co/edit/oNq5lmjtjRDaEkzKsrR2?p=preview

But in this example the fieldname is hardcoded.

I tryed to set the fieldname via scope variable into the template. This is not working:

http://plnkr.co/edit/yEl04xyFR5RWYCmI2bMH?p=preview

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <fieldset field-name="{{model.fieldName}}" label-text="{{model.label}}" ng-model="model.value">
  <fieldset>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.directive('fieldset', function(){
  return {
    template: '<label ng-class="{invalid:$parent.myForm[{{fieldName}}].$invalid}">{{lbl}}</label>: ' +
              '<input name="{{fieldName}}" ng-model="value" required>',
    restrict : 'E',
    scope : {
              value : '=ngModel',
              lbl : '@labelText',
              fieldName : '@'
            },

    link : function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      console.log(scope.$parent.myForm);
    }        
  }
})

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.model = {
    fieldName : 'myField',
    label : 'Label for Field',
    value : 6
  } 
});
```

The fieldname in scope.$parent.myForm is '{{fieldName}}' instead of 'myField'. But in DOM the fieldname is assigned as expected.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Sadly, `name` property cannot be set dynamically if you want to use ng-form, and that's because ng-form directive is linked before the expressions in `name` attributes are interpolated. Are you going to use your `fieldset` directive inside ng-repeat? If not, then you can simply set the `name` to "arbitraryDummyString" and your form validation will work.

Comment: Unfortunatly is is used with database fields, usually with ng-repeat. Isn't there a way to add an attribute with a binding in the directive?
In that case I could first use a dummyName, and in my linking fuction add the binding to the real Name and create the associated key in the linking function like this:

    `link : function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      var form = scope.$parent.myForm;
      var name = scope.fieldName;
      
      form[name] = form.dummyName;
      form[name].$name = name;
      
      delete form.dummyName;
      elem.find('input').attr('name',name);

    }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stewie is absolutely right. If the ng-model directive is created it will immediately be registered at the form. If you have a look at the angular sources you will find that the ngModels are registered by their current name in the array `form`:

```
if (control.$name) {
  form[control.$name] = control;
}
```

In your case this is '{{fieldName}}'. This `name` can not be changed, because it is the key in the array. So what can we do to change this? If we have a look at the <kbd>[FormController API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aform.FormController)</kbd> we can see there are functions to remove (`$removeControl`) or add (`$addControl`) controls. Both functions require the NgModelController as input parameter. E.g. the NgModelController that angular has created for our input element. We have access to this controller by:

var modelController = inputElement.controller('ngModel');

I think we have now all information together to write the directive:

```js
app.directive('fieldset', function(){
  return {
    template: '<label ng-class="{invalid:form[fieldName].$invalid}">{{lbl}}</label>: ' +
              '<input name="{{fieldName}}" ng-model="value" required>',
    restrict : 'E',
    require: '^form', // we need the parent NgFormController 
    scope : {
              value : '=ngModel',
              lbl : '@labelText',
              fieldName : '@'
         },

    link : function(scope, elem, attrs, formCtrl) {
       // get the NgModelController for the input element
       var modelCtrl = elem.find('input').controller('ngModel');

       // remove the ModelController from the FormController
       formCtrl.$removeControl(modelCtrl); 
       // set the right name
       modelCtrl.$name = scope.fieldName; 
       // add the namend ModelController to the FormController
       formCtrl.$addControl(modelCtrl); 

       // publish the FormController to the scope - so we don't need to mess around with the parent scope.
       scope.form = formCtrl;
    }
  }
})
```

I would also suggest publish the NgFormController to the directives scope. So you may write your css condition:

```
form[fieldName].$invalid
```

instad of:

```
$parent.myForm[fieldName].$invalid
```

It is more generic, because you don't need to know the name of your form.

<kbd>[PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/yJ7P8kDGmIYMNKRJPH44?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: This is such a great answer. I wish all answers were this informative and well-explained.

Answer (score 2):

`ng-form` directive is linked before the view expressions on child elements are interpolated. This is why you can't have dynamic field names if you want to make use of angular form validation.

But, when creating the form fields dynamically (through `ng-repeat`), the fields don't really need to have unique `name` attribute. That's because you're allowed to wrap each form element into it's own private *ng-form scope*:

<kbd>[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wzk5SatZUjQkMW1tYQ3g?p=preview)</kbd>

```js
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.fields = [
    {label: 'First Name', required: false},
    {label: 'Last Name', required: false},
    {label: 'Email', required: true}
  ];

});
```

```html
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <form name="form" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="save()" novalidate>

    <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="field in fields" ng-form="form">
      <label class="control-label" ng-class="{required: field.required}">{{field.label}}</label>
      <input 
        type="text" 
        name="field" 
        ng-model="field.value" 
        class="form-control" 
        ng-required="field.required"
      />
      <span 
        class="help-block error"
        ng-show="form.field.$dirty && form.field.$error.required"
      >{{field.label}} is required</span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn">Cancel</button>
    </div>

  </form>

</body>
```

Comment: OK, that makes it more clear. But could you show also an example with ng-repeat and isolated scope in directive? In an isolated scope I don't have the form in my scope to access the field. Therefore I tryed to access it like scope.$parent.myFormName.myFieldName - but this seems not to be the right way.

Comment: Please refer to @michael's answer for information on how to get access to ngFormController from inside the isolated scope.